# PHP variable, adding a word in between

Tags: php, variables

I got this variable

```
$test = 'Alpha, Gamma, Beta';
```

What is the best practice to get this result? How do I add a certain word in between such as I did below add **Rays**.

**Alpha Rays, Gamma Rays, Beta Rays**

Comment: Is the string always going to be of the form 'something{comma}{space}'... ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code piece

```
$test = preg_replace('/(,|$)/', ' Rays$1', $test);
```

I can't tell if it is "Best practice", but it is *a* practice that works and is simple. You can probably make another solution which would give you better performance, and that might be "best practice" if performance is the issue.

But if simplicity is the way, this is good.

**Edit:**

Since some other answers are using `str_replace`, I can give a working solution for that too:

```
$test = str_replace(',',' Rays,', $test).(empty($test)?'':' Rays');
```

Comment: in above code (last code line) It comes in this order 'Alpha Rays, Beta, Rays, Gamma Rays'. 

How to bring it this way ' Rays Alpha, Rays Beta, RAys Gamma' ?

Comment: @Mas: If you refer to the line using `str_replace`, you can place the word first this way: `$test = (empty($test)?'':'Rays ').str_replace(',', ', Rays', $test);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the str_replace function for every comma it finds.

Example:

```
$str = str_replace("," , " Rays," , $test.' Rays');
```

You can find more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

use explode

```
$x = explode(",", $test);
```

then implode

```
$x = implode(" Ray ,", $x);
```

or foreach and add something different. 
[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) - [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: `Beta` won't get any 'Rays' using this solution I am afraid.